# Index Match in VBA, Match Property/Type Mismatch Errors

Tags: excel, vba, function

I am trying to mirror an index/match function from excel using VBA to copy over notes from an older version of one spreadsheet to a new one. If the value on my new sheet (the summary sheet) does not equal the corresponding value on my original sheet, and if it does not equal zero, I want to copy over the information from the original sheet onto my new sheet (the summary sheet).

I tried using WorksheetFunciton in VBA to utilize the index/match functions in excel to do the comparison, but when I ran the code I got the following error: "Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunciton ." I tried changing how I call the match function from WorksheetFunction to Application.Match, but this gave me a runtime error 13 (type mismatch).

I'm not sure what I need to do to get this code to work. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

```
Sub Notes()

Workbooks("Shortages.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Summary").Activate
        Dim y, rng As Range
        Set rng = Range("F11", Range("F11").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
        
        For Each y In rng
        If y.Value <> Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Worksheets("Original").Range("A1:AZ10000"), _
                Application.Match(y.End(xlToLeft).Value, Worksheets("Original").Range("A:A"), 0), _
                Application.Match(y.End(xlUp).Value, Worksheets("Original").Range("1:1"), 0)) And y.Value <> 0 Then
            y.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Worksheets("Original").Range("A1:AZ10000"), _
                Application.Match(y.End(xlToLeft).Value, Worksheets("Original").Range("A:A"), 0), _
                Application.Match(y.End(xlUp).Value, Worksheets("Original").Range("1:1"), 0)).Value
        End If
        Next y
    
End Sub
```

Comment: If you have a working Excel formula, you can use it in VBA with [Application.Evaluate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate).

Comment: `Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunciton` I think you spelled WorksheetFunction incorrectly and that's why it failed to find `WorksheetFunction.Match`

Comment: You will get that "unable to find..." error if the Match does not find the value you're looking for.  Dropping the `WorksheetFunction` skips that run-time error but now you're feeding an error value into Index which gives you a type mismatch instead.  Basically if you're using `Application.Match` you should *always* check to see if you get an error value back before trying any further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something more like this:

```vb
Sub Notes()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook, wsSumm As Worksheet, wsOrig As Worksheet
    Dim y As Range, rng As Range, rMatch As Variant, cMatch As Variant
    
    Set wb = Workbooks("Shortages.xlsm")
    Set wsSumm = wb.Sheets("Summary")
    Set wsOrig = wb.Sheets("Original") '<<< edited was "Summary"...
   
    Set rng = wsSumm.Range("F11", wsSumm.Range("F11").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
        
    For Each y In rng.Cells
        'no run-time error if you drop the `WorksheetFunction`...
        rMatch = Application.Match(y.End(xlToLeft).Value, wsOrig.Range("A:A"), 0)
        cMatch = Application.Match(y.End(xlUp).Value, wsOrig.Range("1:1"), 0)
        '...then check for no-matches
        If Not IsError(rMatch) And Not IsError(cMatch) Then
            y.Value = wsOrig.Cells(rMatch, cMatch)
        End If
    
    Next y
        
End Sub
```

Note the `End(xlToLeft)` and `End(xlUp)` are susceptible to empty cells in your data, so it would be better to specify a fixed column/row there...

Comment: When I run this code I keep getting errors for the rMatch and cMatch variables. I made a copy of my summary sheet, renamed it 'original' and changed some of the values in the table to test out the code I wrote as well as the code you provided. The match functions should find corresponding values for any input because I never changed any of the entries in column A or row 1 when making the 'original' sheet to run my tests. Any idea what's preventing the function from pulling any value?

Comment: Check the value of `y.End(xlToLeft).Value` and also `y.End(xlToLeft).Address` to make sure it's pulling from the correct cell.  If there's a specific row/column it should be using to pick up the match value then (eg) `y.Entirerow.Columns("E").Value` would be more reliable than using `End()`

Comment: ...plus I just noticed I had the same name "summary" for both sheets (fixed above)